# How to ping internal application url through Linux?

Tags: linux, ping

I want to ping internal application URL like http://test.com:8080/ , but it through error as unknown host , because there is DNS server or no standard setting for this server.

Thats means i have internal application which means application running in within network(only our network can access this application). if ping this url , it throws unknown host.

Please advise is there any way to ping internal application ?

Comment: What are you saying ?

Comment: if the host is unknown, it is not on your network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ping hosts, not applications. `ping` relies on the ICMP protocol, which is completely outside of TCP, so it has no concept of ports (ports are a TCP thing). What you need to do is make sure that your `test.com` resolves to the correct IP address (the simplest way to do it would be to put the address statically into `/etc/hosts`).

For example, if you're test.com is at 10.0.0.1, your `/etc/hosts` on your local machine should contain a line with `10.0.0.1  test.com` or you should ping 10.0.0.1 directly (`ping 10.0.0.1`).

Additionally, on the server, make sure that incoming ICMP requests aren't ignored (`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`) (usually by default, they aren't).